# Getting dimensions from nib entities before they are displayed

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, nib

I have a nib file, in which I have created an `NSView`.

This view has two states. If it is "Off," then only some items at the top are visible. If it is "On," then the entire view is visible (disclosure triangle thing).

Now, I currently have the display rect hardcoded (using `static const`). However, I want to be able to change the nib, and not have to go and tweak any magic numbers.

Simple enough. I simply get the frame property of some nib elements, and Bob's your uncle.

I need to get these dimensions before the view is displayed. It is instantiated, but has `CGRectZero` as the frame for everything until it's displayed.

Is there a "proper" way to extract the dimensions in code for nib items from a loaded (but not displayed) nib?

Comment: have you looked at `awakeFromNib`?

Comment: I'll have to mess with this some more tomorrow. I'm using autolayout, and it sort of looks like AL hasnt been applied by awakeFromNib, as I am getting some very strange dimensions.

Comment: That did it, thanks! Feel free to post a solution, so I can give you a nice green checkmark!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the `awakeFromNib` method, which is called after the nib is loaded so that you can configure the view before it is displayed.